# Unknown column 'difference' in 'where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my code:

```
select a.id_brg, a.nm_brg, a.jen_sat, a.nm_kat,a.stok,a.laku, (a.stok-a.laku) as difference from (SELECT barang.id_brg, barang.nm_brg, jen_sat, nm_kat, SUM( IFNULL(  stok_brg.stok, 0 ) ) AS stok, IFNULL( laku, 0 ) AS laku
        FROM barang
        JOIN satuan ON barang.id_sat = satuan.id_sat
        JOIN kategori ON barang.id_kat = kategori.id_kat
        LEFT JOIN stok_brg ON barang.id_brg = stok_brg.id_brg
        LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT barang.id_brg, SUM( IFNULL( brg_laku.dibeli, 0 ) ) AS laku
        FROM barang, brg_laku
        WHERE barang.id_brg = brg_laku.id_brg
        GROUP BY barang.id_brg ASC
        ) AS brg_laku ON barang.id_brg = brg_laku.id_brg
        GROUP BY barang.id_brg ASC) as a;
```

How to add `where` in that code?

```
where difference <= 3
```

Every time I write `where`, I get error message:

> Unknown column 'difference' in where clause

Comment: you can use `where (a.stok-a.laku) <= 3`

Comment: Asked a million times. You can't use a column alias in the `where` clause. Search for the name of your DBMS product and `alias` here on SO.

Comment: yeah you're right thanks for your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id_brg, 
       a.nm_brg, 
       a.jen_sat,
       a.nm_kat,
       a.stok,
       a.laku,
      (a.stok-a.laku) as difference 
FROM (
      SELECT barang.id_brg,
             barang.nm_brg,
             jen_sat, 
             nm_kat, 
             SUM(IFNULL(stok_brg.stok, 0)) AS stok,
             IFNULL(laku, 0) AS laku
      FROM barang
      JOIN satuan ON barang.id_sat = satuan.id_sat
      JOIN kategori ON barang.id_kat = kategori.id_kat
      LEFT JOIN stok_brg ON barang.id_brg = stok_brg.id_brg
      LEFT JOIN (
                 SELECT barang.id_brg,
                        SUM(IFNULL( brg_laku.dibeli, 0 )) AS laku
                 FROM barang 
                 INNER JOIN brg_laku
                 ON barang.id_brg = brg_laku.id_brg
                 GROUP BY barang.id_brg ASC
                ) AS brg_laku 
     ON barang.id_brg = brg_laku.id_brg
     GROUP BY barang.id_brg ASC
    ) as a
WHERE (a.stok-a.laku) <= 3;
```

Now, **Can you use an alias in the WHERE clause in MySQL?**

From the MySQL Manual:

> It is not allowable to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause
>   because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE
>   clause is executed. See Section B.1.5.4, “[Problems with Column
>   Aliases](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html)”.

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
Select * from (select a.id_brg, a.nm_brg, a.jen_sat, a.nm_kat,a.stok,a.laku, (a.stok-a.laku) as difference from (SELECT barang.id_brg, barang.nm_brg, jen_sat, nm_kat, SUM( IFNULL(  stok_brg.stok, 0 ) ) AS stok, IFNULL( laku, 0 ) AS laku
        FROM barang
        JOIN satuan ON barang.id_sat = satuan.id_sat
        JOIN kategori ON barang.id_kat = kategori.id_kat
        LEFT JOIN stok_brg ON barang.id_brg = stok_brg.id_brg
        LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT barang.id_brg, SUM( IFNULL( brg_laku.dibeli, 0 ) ) AS laku
        FROM barang, brg_laku
        WHERE barang.id_brg = brg_laku.id_brg
        GROUP BY barang.id_brg ASC
        ) AS brg_laku ON barang.id_brg = brg_laku.id_brg
        GROUP BY barang.id_brg ASC) as a;select a.id_brg, a.nm_brg, a.jen_sat, a.nm_kat,a.stok,a.laku, (a.stok-a.laku) as difference from (SELECT barang.id_brg, barang.nm_brg, jen_sat, nm_kat, SUM( IFNULL(  stok_brg.stok, 0 ) ) AS stok, IFNULL( laku, 0 ) AS laku
        FROM barang
        JOIN satuan ON barang.id_sat = satuan.id_sat
        JOIN kategori ON barang.id_kat = kategori.id_kat
        LEFT JOIN stok_brg ON barang.id_brg = stok_brg.id_brg
        LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT barang.id_brg, SUM( IFNULL( brg_laku.dibeli, 0 ) ) AS laku
        FROM barang, brg_laku
        WHERE barang.id_brg = brg_laku.id_brg
        GROUP BY barang.id_brg ASC
        ) AS brg_laku ON barang.id_brg = brg_laku.id_brg
        GROUP BY barang.id_brg ASC) as a)fq where  difference <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference a column alias inside the same `SELECT` you are declaring it. Either you filter by the column expression (`a.stok-a.laku`) or you nest it as a subquery and filter it in an outmost scope.

Filter by the column expression:

```
select 
    a.id_brg, 
    a.nm_brg, 
    a.jen_sat, 
    a.nm_kat,
    a.stok,
    a.laku, 
    (a.stok-a.laku) as difference 
from 
    (SELECT 
        barang.id_brg, 
        barang.nm_brg, 
        jen_sat, 
        nm_kat, 
        SUM( IFNULL(  stok_brg.stok, 0 ) ) AS stok, IFNULL( laku, 0 ) AS laku
    FROM barang
        JOIN satuan ON barang.id_sat = satuan.id_sat
        JOIN kategori ON barang.id_kat = kategori.id_kat
        LEFT JOIN stok_brg ON barang.id_brg = stok_brg.id_brg
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                barang.id_brg, 
                SUM( IFNULL( brg_laku.dibeli, 0 ) ) AS laku
            FROM 
                barang, brg_laku
            WHERE 
                barang.id_brg = brg_laku.id_brg
            GROUP BY 
                barang.id_brg ASC
            ) AS brg_laku 
                ON barang.id_brg = brg_laku.id_brg
    GROUP BY 
        barang.id_brg ASC) as a
WHERE
    a.stok-a.laku <= 3 -- Here!
```

Nest the subquery:

```
SELECT
    X.*
FROM
    (
    select 
        a.id_brg, 
        a.nm_brg, 
        a.jen_sat, 
        a.nm_kat,
        a.stok,
        a.laku, 
        (a.stok-a.laku) as difference 
    from 
        (SELECT 
            barang.id_brg, 
            barang.nm_brg, 
            jen_sat, 
            nm_kat, 
            SUM( IFNULL(  stok_brg.stok, 0 ) ) AS stok, IFNULL( laku, 0 ) AS laku
        FROM barang
            JOIN satuan ON barang.id_sat = satuan.id_sat
            JOIN kategori ON barang.id_kat = kategori.id_kat
            LEFT JOIN stok_brg ON barang.id_brg = stok_brg.id_brg
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT 
                    barang.id_brg, 
                    SUM( IFNULL( brg_laku.dibeli, 0 ) ) AS laku
                FROM 
                    barang, brg_laku
                WHERE 
                    barang.id_brg = brg_laku.id_brg
                GROUP BY 
                    barang.id_brg ASC
                ) AS brg_laku 
                    ON barang.id_brg = brg_laku.id_brg
        GROUP BY 
            barang.id_brg ASC) as a
    ) AS X
WHERE
    X.difference <= 3 -- Here!
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE (a.stok-a.laku) <= 3` not the alias.

```
SELECT a.id_brg, a.nm_brg, a.jen_sat, a.nm_kat,a.stok,a.laku, (a.stok-a.laku) difference FROM(SELECT B.id_brg, B.nm_brg, jen_sat, nm_kat, SUM( IFNULL(SB.stok, 0 )) stok, IFNULL(laku, 0) laku
FROM barang B
JOIN satuan S ON B.id_sat = S.id_sat
JOIN kategori ON barang.id_kat = kategori.id_kat
LEFT JOIN stok_brg SB ON B.id_brg = SB.id_brg
LEFT JOIN (SELECT B.id_brg, SUM( IFNULL(BL.dibeli, 0)) laku
           FROM barang B
           INNER JOIN brg_laku BL ON B.id_brg = BL.id_brg
           WHERE (a.stok-a.laku) <= 3
           GROUP BY B.id_brg ASC) brg_laku BL ON B.id_brg = BL.id_brg
GROUP BY B.id_brg ASC) a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first get the a.stok and a.laku , calculate the difference and then store it to a sql variable and use it then in a where clause. Because mysql doesn't calculate the difference first in the select case and then fetches the appropriate rows. You have to do this. I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the [`SELECT` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) explains:

> A `select_expr` can be given an alias using `AS alias_name`. The alias is used as the expression's column name and can be used in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, or `HAVING` clauses.
>
> [...]
>
> It is not permissible to refer to a column alias in a `WHERE` clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the `WHERE` clause is executed.
>   See [Section B.5.4.4, "Problems with Column Aliases"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html).

The solution is simple: don't use the alias in the `WHERE` clause, use the aliased expression instead:

```
SELECT ... (a.stok-a.laku) as difference, ...
...
WHERE a.stok-a.laku <= 3
...
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL -- as with all other databases -- does not allow table aliases in the `WHERE` clause.  However, MySQL extends the `HAVING` clause to allow such filtering.  So, you can do:

```
SELECT a.id_brg, a.nm_brg, a.jen_sat, a.nm_kat, a.stok, a.laku,
       (a.stok - a.laku) as difference
FROM (SELECT barang.id_brg, barang.nm_brg, jen_sat, nm_kat,
             SUM(COALESCE(stok_brg.stok, 0 )) AS stok, 
             COALESCE( laku, 0 ) AS laku
      FROM barang JOIN
           satuan
           ON barang.id_sat = satuan.id_sat JOIN
           kategori
           ON barang.id_kat = kategori.id_kat LEFT JOIN
           stok_brg
           ON barang.id_brg = stok_brg.id_brg LEFT JOIN
           (SELECT brg_laku.id_brg, SUM(COALESCE(brg_laku.dibeli, 0)) AS laku
            FROM brg_laku
            GROUP BY brg_laku.id_brg
          ) brg_lak
          ON barang.id_brg = brg_laku.id_brg
     GROUP BY barang.id_brg
    ) as a
HAVING difference <= 3;
```

Notes:

- I prefer `COALESCE()` to `IFNULL()` because the former is the ANSI-standard function.
- I simplified the last subquery.  The `JOIN` seems unnecessary.  (It might be under some circumstances, but I'm guessing it is not.)
- You probably don't need the `COALESCE()`/`IFNULL()` for the `SUM()`s.  I left them in, but the `NULL`s are ignored in aggregation functions.